# Building in interactivity to a chart using highcharter library in R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-markdown, r-highcharter

I've made a simple multi-line chart using the highcharter library in an RMarkdown.  Here's some simple, made-up data:

```
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(highcharter)
library(DT)
library(formattable)
library(zoo)

year <- c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020)
drugType <- c('drug1', 'drug1', 'drug1', 'drug1', 'drug2', 'drug2', 'drug2', 'drug2', 'drug3', 'drug3', 'drug3', 'drug3', 'drug4', 'drug4', 'drug4', 'drug4')
total <- c(21, 18, 17, 10, 1, 1, 3, 4, 192, 242, 111, 234, 34, 26, 36, 17)
perCapitaRate <- c(1.4, 4.3, 3.4, 3.0, 23.0, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 45.4, 4.4, 4.5, 23.6, 34.7, 22.3, 2.0)
drugDeathsByYr <- data.frame(year, drugType, total, perCapitaRate)


myChart <- hchart(drugDeathsByYr, "line", hcaes(x = year, y=total, group="drugType")) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(line = list(marker = list(enabled = FALSE, symbol="circle"))) %>%
  #hc_tooltip(valuePrefix = "$", valueDecimals = 2) %>%
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Year")) %>%
  hc_yAxis(labels = list(format = "{value:,.0f}"), title = list(text = "# of Fatal Overdoses")) %>%
  hc_title(text = "Overdose Deaths, by Year")
```

Is there a way to add a dropdown or toggle button to change the data displayed in the chart?  Currently, it only displays the field "total" on the y axis.  Ideally I would like the option for the user to be able to toggle between "total" and "perCapitaRate" - in other words, the user selects "per capita rate" on a dropdown menu or button, and the chart updates to show the "perCapitaRate" field.

So, is shiny required to do something like this?  **Looking for a solution that doesn't using shiny**. I'm seeing that highcharter has some built-in interactivity capabilities, such as the `hc_add_series` method listed in the highcharter documentation:

https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/highcharts-for-r-users/

But, I don't see anything that particularly meets my use-case listed above.  I would also be open to finding a solution using HTML/JS within the RMarkdown.. i.e. simply creating two different charts, and when the user clicks a button, the entire chart is simply replaced with a new one.

Comment: You can add a button via Highcharts.SVGRenderer and update a series data by series.update(): Here is the example idea in vanilla JS https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s1wxn2b5/
API references:
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#button
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Comment: Hi - thanks - im trying to do this in R though.. is the idea here you’d write js code within Rmarkdown?

Comment: You can pass the JS code directly to `load()` event , so you can base on the code from the fiddle
`hc_chart(events = list(load = JS("function() {
  var chart = this;
  ...
    }"))) %>%`

Comment: are you able to refer me to documentation or include a very simple example?  Thanks!

Comment: I am not an R developer, however, based on the article https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/ you can use JS code in R, by wrapping it into the List() method. So you can test my solution by copy the load() function content from the fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v8br24fd/ into the following snipped:
  `hc_chart(
    events = list(
      load = JS("function(){
// JS code here
        }")
    )
  ) %>%` and then include it in your chart config.